# Friendly URL with the same pattern

Tags: iis, web-config, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I can redirect and make a single Friendly URL:

```
<rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^Product/Tour\.aspx$" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="Product/Tour" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>

<rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL2" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^Product/Tour$" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="Product/Tour.aspx" />
</rule>
```

But, for example, if I have:

```
http://www.domain.com/Product/Features.aspx
http://www.domain.com/Product/Download.aspx
http://www.domain.com/Product/FAQ.aspx
```

etc.

Can I write one rule to make friendly URL for all of these links in order to receive?

```
http://www.domain.com/Product/Features
http://www.domain.com/Product/Download
http://www.domain.com/Product/FAQ
```

It's easy when there is a couple of links, but with a lot of rules it's hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the regex pattern and the [back reference](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-20-configuration-reference#Using_back-references_in_rewrite_rules) to do this:

```
<rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^Product/([A-z0-9]+)\.aspx$" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="Product/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>

<rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL2" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^Product/([A-z0-9]+)$" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="Product/{R:1}.aspx" />
</rule>
```

If you have a lot of urls to rewrite, you should read the documentation about the [Rewrite Maps](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module) as well.